# Calling External function from within function - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using Phonegap and JQueryMobile to create a web application. I'm new to javascript and am having an issue.

My issue is with calling a function I have in a file named "testscript.js", the function is called testFunc. The testscript.js containts only this:

```
function testFunc() {
    console.log("Yes I work");
}
```

Within my html page I have the following code:

```
<script>
  $('#pageListener').live('pageinit', function(event) 
    {
     testFunc();
    });
</script>
```

The test function is found within my "testscript.js" which I am including with this line within the head tags:

```
<script src="testscript.js"></script>
```

The error I get is a "testFunc is not defined".

I am assuming its some type of scope issue as I'm able to call other jquery functions such as:

```
alert("I work");
```

and I am able to call my functions by sticking them within script tags in the html elsewhere.

I've tried all sorts of ways of calling my function with no success, any help is appreciated!

Comment: What does `testscript.js` look like? In particular the bit defining `testFunc`?

Comment: I have updated my question to show what the testscript.js file and testFunc look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include the testscript.js before the other jquery code in your html. Like this:

```
<script src="testscript.js"></script>

<script>
   $('#pageListener').live('pageinit', function(event) 
   {
      testFunc();
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! That as resolved my problem. However I'm unclear on why I need to include that when its already included between the head tags alongside the other javascript libraries I'm using (Jquery,jquery-mobile etc). Can you explain?

Comment: @Demonofloom: As I said in my answer, as long as `testscript.js` has been loaded by the time PhoneGap calls your `pageinit` handler, it will work. If it started working when you moved your `testscript.js` include, that means that it *hadn't* been loaded when PhoneGap fired your handler -- e.g., your script link was too far down on the page.

Comment: yup. T.J. mentioned it correctly. Its only that your script didn't load when the function was called.

Answer (score 1):

As long as `testscript.js` has been loaded by the time PhoneGap fires the `pageinit` event, and provided the `testFunc` function is a global, there's no reason that shouldn't work.

You haven't shown us your `testFunc`, but my guess is that it's not a global, but rather you have it inside something like, for instance:

```
$('#pageListener').live('pageinit', function(event) 
{
    function testFunc()
    {
        // Do something here
    }
});
```

or just a scoping function

```
(function() 
{
    function testFunc()
    {
        // Do something here
    }
})();
```

Either way, since it's declared within another function, it's local to that function, not global. To call it from another script file, you'll need to be able to get at it from the global namespace (sadly). The best way to do that is **not** to make it a global, but to create just **one** global that you'll put all of your shared stuff on, like this:

```
(function() 
{
    if (!window.MyStuff)
    {
        window.MyStuff = {};
    }
    window.MyStuff.testFunc = testFunc;

    function testFunc()
    {
        // Do something here
    }
})();
```

...which you call like this:

```
$('#pageListener').live('pageinit', function(event) 
{
    MyStuff.testFunc(); // Or: window.MyStuff.testFunc();
});
```

Comment: I think my testFunc is global. I have edited my original question to show what testscript.js looks like.